# can not send post data with xcode 6 beta 5

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6, nsmutableurlrequest

I used Swift to send user,password to server, but server can not receid email,pass.

Pleas let me know, where i am wrong.

OS X 9.5, iOS SDK 8.0, Xcode 6 beta 5

Swift:

```
       //post data
        var post:NSString = "email=\(email_merchant)&password=\(pass_merchant)&appToken=\(token_key)"

        //url login
        var url:NSURL=NSURL.URLWithString("http://xxx.xxx.xxx/api/sessions")

        //add data

        var postData:NSData=post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

        var postLength:NSString = (String)(postData.length)

        var request:NSMutableURLRequest=NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody=postData
        request.setValue(postLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencode", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        request.setValue("d54e952e0d0586fc48f1535883ef7008", forHTTPHeaderField: "appToken")
        //request.H


        var reponseError: NSError?
        var reponse: NSURLResponse?

        var urlData: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &reponse, error: &reponseError)
```

server code:

```
            if(empty($_POST['password']) ){
        echo json_encode(array ("status"=> "empty pass")) ;
        Yii::app()->end();  
    }
```

println( reponse)

O

```
ptional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fea9acb1180> { URL: http://xxx.xxx.xxx/api/sessions } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 43;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Mon, 29 Sep 2014 11:27:29 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
    Server = "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)";
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3";
} })
{
    status = "emmty pass";
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: your server code is not clear. can you post your server code here? how you are retrieving post data in php?

Comment: yes, I am retrieving post data in PHP. I use Yii framework. Maybe the problem is in swift code

Comment: can you post the code? because you cannot access the data with normal post variables when you access through webservices. you need to give with phpinput like this `$data = file_get_contents("php://input");`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the data with normal post variables, when you access through webservices. you need to give with phpinput like this `$data = file_get_contents("php://input");`

Answer (score 1):

It's `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, not `application/x-www-form-urlencode`.